# ASP.NET core app Windows Authentication, running on EC2 Linux instance

Tags: asp.net, windows, authentication, amazon-ec2

Problem Statement is - I have one EC2 linux instance on which ASP.NET core web application is deployed. I want to do the windows authentication for that application.
I am a fresher with not much experience in the field of development. I have tried searching on the Google but could not find any relevant document that can help in achieving the objective.
Can anyone from the community provide information on how to do the windows authentication for the app running on EC2 ?

Comment: Can you show what you got so far?

Comment: Was given an ASP. NET core application which we deployed on EC2 linux. Now we have to authenticate users by using windows authentication. Actually we have done windows authentication but it will only run on IIS EXPRESS. We are looking for ways through which authentication can work on EC2 Linux.